# Make an absolute positioned div visible on hover and navigable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an absolute positioned `div` that is shown on hover of an `a`. Since it is absolutely positioned at the base of the anchor (`top:0; left:0`), **I wish to let the user to move from the anchor to the div without hiding the div**.

Actually, I prepared a piece of JQuery code, but I've only be capable to let the div to be shown on hover. When I move from the anchor to the div, the latter is obsiously hidden.
Look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbZkJ/) to look what I did.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are over complicating everything by using javascript.  You do not need it in this case, as you can just use a parent container to handle the hover action.

I would personally do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qLUf9/

```
<div class="hover_container">
    <a class="button">Click Me</a>
    <div class="container">
       This is my hover content.
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
a.button {
 background-color: blue;
 color: #fff;
}

.hover_container {
 position: relative:  
}

.hover_container .container {
 display: none;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 20px;
}

.hover_container:hover .container {
 display: block;
}
```

**Please note:** IE6 does not support the `:hover` attribute on block elements.  For IE6 and below, you must use some basic javascript to add a class such as `hovered` to that element.  You can read more about fixing the IE6 hover bug here: http://robspangler.com/blog/hover-pseudo-class-bug-fix-for-ie6/

Comment: There are some typos and unnecessary properties in your code and in your fiddle.

Comment: Can you point them out? (instead of just down-voting my solution, which happens to work regardless of the "typos")

Comment: I had not voted you down ;-) The only property in the second block have to end width a semicolon instead of a double point. And setting a div to `float:anything` *and* `position:absolute` is useless.

Comment: Axel! I have to say that I tested your solution and it seems to work very well! Just let me one more day to ensure that it is not buggy! If it works (and it seems to be right), I will accept your answer because it will reduce my need for JS, it is very elegant, clean and easy! For the moment, get a **+1**! Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ok! I prepared a modified version of yours to show the problem I face when I use this approach. This is why I prefer Javascript. Get a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qLUf9/1/). As you may see, when I set z-index, the div is shown under another div with the same z-index.

Comment: @Axel I changed all the code to minimize the use of z-index. Now it works without Javascript. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the div by the link. This way hovering the div would also be recognized as hovering the link because it is a parent.

```
<a>
    Hover Me!
    <div>Hidden Message.</div>
</a>
```

You don't need javascript at all for this task.

Wait a minute for my fiddle. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xwder/1/

Alternatively you could wrap the `a` and the `div` both with another container, so that you don't have children inside the link. Check out Alex's answer for that.

Comment: Well, I know this solution (e.g. it is used for menus), but it doesn't work for me. When I use this approach the div is not shown as due. It is shown only inside the container of the anchor (which is a div with display:table-cell. Do you think that one can follow another way?

Comment: It's not good practice wrapping block elements with inline block elements. `a` is an inline-block and `div` is a block.

Comment: @Axel. That's why I set the link to `inline-block`.
@Kryptonite. Try again please, it now works for me in Chrome and Firefox.
@JeanValjean. Does it still not work? An often made mistake is to set to offset of the div to big so that it will close before the cursor reached it.

Comment: There is a single line between the link and div that is causing problems if you move the mouse slowly.

Comment: @Kryptonite. I decreased the offset of the div. Please try again at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xwder/2/

Comment: Works :) but the div inside the link upsets me ;_;

Comment: As far as I now it is a common approach. If you set the `a` to `display:inline-block;` it should be acceptable, what do you think? ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17080/discussion-between-kryptonite-and-sharethis)

Comment: @sharethis The CSS definitions have nothing to do with semantically correct HTML.  You should state that this is only correct in HTML5 spec and above.  Wrapping blocks with inline-blocks is not allowed in HTML4 and below and will not validate correctly.

Comment: Maybe you are right, then set the link to `display:block;` or use a wrapper like in your (Axel's) answer.

Comment: @sharethis As promised I prepared a small example to show you why I'm using Javascript. Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLUf9/2/) that reproduces the  Axel's solution. As you may see, the  div is shown below the following anchor. I think that it is due to the box-model used by the browser.

Comment: That is because the tooltip of the first link is *inside the first link*. The second link by default is above the previous one. I don't know a workaround, I am sorry. (You could remove the `position:relative;` of the wrapper element but then you can't set the position of the tooltip relative to the position of the wrapper.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think it does what you want without altering your code too much. :)

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnztk/)

Comment: I commented out the line that fades out the div when you move out of the link. Then I added a hover out handler for the div that hides it when the mouse leaves it.

Comment: Ok! I see the difference. It works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please, consider to enrich your own question! Otherwise, in one day I will edit you answer! It is very useful and original!

Comment: Why would you want to use an complicated javascript solution instead of some lines CSS? Ok, nearly everyone has javascript enabled, that is no argument. But the CSS solution is much simpler and more performant. If you want you can also create a fading effect using `transition`s.

Comment: @sharethis Because I do more than what I shown. I can bother all of you with larger codes. I suppose I only put the fundamentals. However, I will prepare another JSfiddle to show you why I'm using Javascript.